# "Cannot read properties of undefined," even though data is there (React/JSX)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, graphql, jsx

I need to map over an array of novels a user has saved in order to render info cards on each novel. Each time I try, the page fails to load and I get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')--attempting to read the novel's name etc. The query works perfectly on the back end, and I'm able to console log all of the data in the browser, so I'm not sure why I'm getting "undefined."

I've found that I'm able to render data from the user level, but not the "novels" sub-level. So I think the problem may have something to do with the mapping?

Here is the query:

```
{
  user {
    _id
    name
    novels {
      _id
      name
      author
      rank
      isComplete
    }
  }
}
```

And relevant code from the component:

```
    if (data) {
        user = data.user

        console.log(user.novels)
    }
return (
        <>
                <div className="row">
                    {user ? (
                        <>
                            <h2>Your Novels:</h2>
                            {user.novels.map((novel) => (
                                <div
                                    key={novel._id}
                                    className="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 card">
                                    <p>  {novel.name}
                                        < br />
                                        <span className="card-subheader" >by</span> {novel.author}
                                        < br />
                                        <span className="card-subheader">Rank:</span> {novel.rank}
                                        < br />
                                        <span key={novel.isComplete}>{novel.isComplete}</span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        ) : null}
                </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

So basically, it's able to render `user.name` for example, but not `user.novel.name`

Any help would be SO appreciated! (And this is my first post, so apologies in advance if I'm missing anything)

Comment: what is `console.log(user)` giving? Just to verify if the `user.novels` is an array or an object

Comment: So actually `user.novels` is an array of objects: `15: {__typename: 'Novel', _id: '61bb535508015458de004f27', name: 'Catch-22', author: 'Joseph Heller', rank: '9', …}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not fault of your code in the frontend. You should check `user` in `console`. It may `user.novels` contain an empty objects caused an error reading `novel.name`, like this:

```
{
  user: {
    _id: ...
    name: ...
    novels: [
      null or {}, // novel is null so reading novel.name cause the error. 
      {
        _id: ...
        name: ...
        author: ...
        rank: ...
        isComplete: ...
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
}
```

However you can check this in frontend, but technically these empty objects should not be in your response from backend and should fix them.

Comment: I don't agree with the statement "technically these empty objects should not be in your response from backend". It depends on the GraphQL schema. If `novels` is a list of nullable objects, then a null object in the list is perfectly valid. I'd be willing to bet that the `novels` list is indeed a list of nullable objects because otherwise the GraphQL engine would most likely throw an error when trying to serialize `null` as a "Novel" object

Comment: This was it! I had made IDs for novels non-nullable, but there were some nulls hiding  in the collection from my earlier, less successful days in the graphql playground. Thanks for this!

Comment: @AshleyTate if this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @EricDauenhauer that's the point!